spring cloud config server adding a default application name "app"
Spring cloud config assumes that I have an application name called "app"
I am using spring cloud config server version 4.1.3 and trying to have a repo per application settings and and have the following configuration
server:
  port: 8888
spring:
  application:
    name: configserver
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/myusername/{application}
          default-label: main
          timeout: 5
#          clone-on-start: true
#          force-pull: true
          username: myusername
          password: mypassword
          refresh-rate: 1
          search-paths:
            - dev/*
      name: microservice-config
  config:
    name: bootstrap
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework:
      cloud: DEBUG


when I run the application, I found that when the application starts up it trying to load the configuration from an application called "app", after I debug my code I found that it goes to class called ConfigServerHealthIndicator that contains the following code
@PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        if (this.repositories.isEmpty()) {
            this.repositories.put("app", new Repository());
        }
    }

but I found a workaround by disabling the health indicator by the following config
spring.cloud.config.server.health.enabled=false

this solve the issue, but I want to know the following

why this is happening(why the health indicator creates a default app although I added configuration for my repositories)
and how to disable it without disable the health indicator
how to add a default repo that contain default configuration for all the microservices

Thanks.

Are you sure the application you are running is reading that configuration file (profile)? That code look exactly for the configuration under spring.cloud.config.server.git if that if if (this.repositories.isEmpty()) is returning true it means it did not read that file

@JorgeCampos when the application starts up it trying to read that default "app" but when I try to hit my configuration like /orders/default it gets the configuration normally, I think that the problem is that I uses an expression {application} so it did not found a default application to do healthcheck  on it so it creates this default one
